# C++: std::vector insert with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp, stdvector

I'm getting a segmentation fault in the following function that creates a grid of points in parallel with OpenMP using vector insert.

```
std::vector<n_point_t> fill_points(size_t Nn1, size_t Nn2) {
    std::vector<n_point_t> grid;
    grid.reserve(Nn1*Nn2);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t i=0; i<Nn1; i++) {
        std::vector<n_point_t> subgrid = get_subgrid(Nn2);
        grid.insert(grid.begin()+i*Nn2, subgrid.begin(), subgrid.end());
    }
    return grid;
}
```

`n_point_t` is defined as

```
union n_point_t {
    double coords[6];
    struct {
        double n1x;
        double n1y;
        double n1z;
        double n2x;
        double n2y;
        double n2z;
    };
};
```

and `get_subgrid(size_t Nn2)` creates a grid of `n_point_t` of size `Nn2`.

The insert is definitely responsible for the segmentation fault. I don't understand the problem here. Each thread should be inserting into a different part of the `grid` because of the insert indexing.

I get a segmentation fault even if I protect the insert with `#pragma omp critical`.

Comment: This is a stupendously bad idea.  Vector insertion modifies the vector's contents and invalidates iterators.  You're also using iterators that can potentially be way past the end when you do `begin() + i * Nn2`.  Why not allocate the vector up-front and have your function fill the values in-place?

Comment: Did I not allocate up-front already with `reserve()`? I'm new to c++, and this is roughly how I would do it in python with numpy arrays. How could `begin() + i * Nn2` be past the end of the vector if I'm reserving up to `Nn1*Nn2` for the vector? I've written it this way because I want `get_subgrid()` to be available to users of this code if they want to custom build a grid themselves.

Comment: You allocated _capacity_ but the vector still contains zero elements, so `begin() == end()`.  Insertion is adding elements to the vector.  Try `resize` instead of `reserve` and then copy your data in-place instead of using `insert`.  Also, are you _certain_ (from code profiling) that using OpenMP will be faster for this simple array initialization?  It seems to me you're doing a lot of unnecessary allocation and then you also have overhead of thread synchronization, which could likely be defeated by a naive single-threaded initializer, unless your subgrid call is expensive.

Comment: I see! I thought `reserve()` was similar to `np.empty()`. I can use resize. Honestly, I was parallelizing this as a practice problem to iron out any problems building with OpenMP and to practice the OpenMP I learned years ago. I will need OpenMP at other points in the project, but it's not really necessary here. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you do call `reserve()` in advance,  no reallocation will happen here. But you are passing a dangerous argument `grid.begin()+i*Nn2` to `insert`. It is not guaranteed to be a valid iterator.

What if the length of `subgrid` is less than `N2`? Will you get an uncontinuous vector? Please do not do so. It works in a single thread, just because `grid.begin()+i*Nn2` happens to be valid. In another word, do not try to touch the unused memory of a vector.

One suggested solution maybe be `resize()` the vector and assign them if you must use multiple threads.